# comparar cadenas de valores permitidos en javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo el siguiente problema quiero comparar 1 cadena con el valor de unos input como valores permitidos pero sinceramente no logro hacer que la comparación se lleve acabo.

obtengo los valores de un formulario se la siguiente forma

```
function obtenerdatosfrm(idfr){ //función que obtiene datos del formulario X
  const form = document.getElementById(idfr);
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  return formData;
}
```

posterior en mi html tengo un boton que llama a funcion `agregar_nuevo_proveedor()`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="agregarnuevo" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onclick="agregar_nuevo_proveedor('form_para_agregar_nuevo_proveedor')">Agregar</button>
```

la función agregar_nuevo_proveedor:

```
function agregar_nuevo_proveedor(idform){
  vacios= validarfrmvacio(idform);
  if(vacios>0){
    Swal.fire('Tienes campos vacíos')
  }else{
    let datosdelfrm= obtenerdatosfrm(idform);
    for (const valor of datosdelfrm.entries()) {
      permitidos= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789@-_.'; 
      for ($i=0; $i< valor[1].length; $i++){ 
        if(){//comparáramos si en valor[1] tiene un tiene algún dato no permitido de la variable permitidos. 
        } 
        
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: hacer esto en `js` no tiene sentido.. cualquier puede vulnerar el codigo en tu frontend ... esto deberias de hacerlo en tu backend.

Comment: Técnicamente, @ArcanisGK507, eso debe hacerse en el backend **Y** en el frontend. No tiene sentido dejar que el 99% de los usuarios que no saben vulnerar la seguridad de JS puedan enviar una llamada al back que no es válida.

Comment: a si es encontré la respuesta en el backend pero quiero asegurarme y hacerlo en el frontend

Comment: ya te deje una respuesta pero voy a mejorarla con `regex` y `test()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para la version de frontend seria asi, siguiendo tu ejemplo, solo la validacion:

```js
function validate($stringToVal)
{
  let inputArr = $stringToVal.split('');
  let permitidos= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789@-_.';
  for ($i=0; $i<inputArr.length; $i++){
    if(!permitidos.includes(inputArr[$i])){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(validate('esteEsUnTextoValido.'));
console.log(validate('esteEsUnTexto NO Valido.'));
```

otra opcion puede ser implementando `regex` y `test()`

```js
function validate($stringToVal)
{
  return /^([0-9A-Za-z_\-.@])*$/g.test($stringToVal);
}

console.log(validate('esteEsUnTextoValido.')); // es valido
console.log(validate('esteEsUnTexto NO Valido.')); // es invalido
console.log(validate('galaxy-big_correo@joder.com')); // es valido
console.log(validate('galaxy%-big!_correo@joder.com')); // es invalido
```

documentacion: test tomara la expresion regular de la izquiera y validara si el texto pasado como parametro cumple con lo esperado en el regex como patron, [Liga](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

***por que esto es vulnerable:*** me puedo saltar esta validacion en el frontend

si yo inyecto via consola una re-escritura de la funcion antes de que se solicite la validacion:

```js
//funcion cargada por tu script:

function validate($stringToVal)
{
  return /^([0-9A-Za-z_\-.@])*$/g.test($stringToVal);
}

//funcion injectada desde la consola del navegador

function validate($stringToVal)
{
  return true;
}

//evaluacion de texto cuando se le da click ... etc

console.log(validate('esteEsUnTextoValido.')); // es valido pero retornara true
console.log(validate('esteEsUnTexto NO Valido.')); // es invalido pero retornara true
console.log(validate('galaxy-big_correo@joder.com')); // es valido pero retornara true
console.log(validate('galaxy%-big!_correo@joder.com')); // es invalido pero retornara true
```

Comment: gracias en verdad !!

Comment: @Gomaru he agregado la version corta con `regex` y `test()`

Comment: @Gomaru tambien agregue al final por que considero que esta validacion es innecesaria... y por que puede ser vandalizada... sigo repitiendo esto debe ser validado en el backend...